# react useState not working with new Date() as initial value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I want to use current Date as a state in my component using useState hooks. So I made this...

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Date from "./components/Date/Date";

import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Date selectedDate={date} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

But it throws this error when I am setting my initial date as a new Date object.

[image]

Comment: what the usage of `date` inside `Date` component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your component is named `Date`, like the `Date` object you trying to use:

```
// Rename
import DateComponent from "./components/Date/Date";

// Will call the constructor of Date object
new Date();
```